# TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I already define error. however, it is giving error that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined"

I am stock here. I will appreciate idea to go beyond this.

Thank you for your help.

Error screenshot

[image]

Signup Component code

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import { signup } from '../../../actions/auth';


const SignupComponent = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        email: '',
        phonenumber: '',
        password: '',
        confirmpassword: '',
        howdidyouknowaboutus: '',
        error: '',
        loading: false,
        message: '',
        showForm: true

    });

    const {firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, password, confirmpassword, howdidyouknowaboutus, error, loading, message, showForm} = values;

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        /* console.table({firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, password, confirmpassword,howdidyouknowaboutus, 
            error, loading, message, showForm}); */
        setValues({...values, loading: true, error: false})
        const user = {firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, password, confirmpassword, howdidyouknowaboutus}

        signup(user).then(data => {
            if (data.error) { ----------------------------------------------- The line with the error
                setValues({...values, error: data.error, loading: false});
            }else{
                setValues({
                    ...values, 
                    firstname: '', 
                    lastname: '', 
                    email: '', 
                    phonenumber: '', 
                    password: '', 
                    confirmpassword: '', 
                    howdidyouknowaboutus: '', 
                    error: '', 
                    loading: false, 
                    message: data.message,
                    showForm: false
                });
            }
        });
    };

   
};

export default SignupComponent;
```

Thank you

Comment: log the response and check the data.error field value you will get some idea.

Comment: the issue could also be living on `signup` action, if it doesn't return data accordingly.

Comment: Hey. I am having the same error. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

**UPD**

```
signup(user).then(data => {
     if (data) { // check here if data not undefined
        if (data.error) {
            setValues({...values, error: data.error, loading: false});
        }else{
            setValues({
                ...values, 
                firstname: '', 
                lastname: '', 
                email: '', 
                phonenumber: '', 
                password: '', 
                confirmpassword: '', 
                howdidyouknowaboutus: '', 
                error: '', 
                loading: false, 
                message: data.message,
                showForm: false
            });
        }
    } else {
         // probably here you would need to do something if dada is undefined
    }
});
```

**Previous reply**

Change it to

```
if (data && data.error)
```

to be sure that data is defined

Comment: I got another error -  message undefined


 signup(user).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data && data.error) {
                setValues({...values, error: data.error, loading: false});
            }else{
                setValues({
                    ...values, 
                    firstname: '', 
                    error: '', 
                    loading: false, 
                    message: data.message, ---------- Error point. Data seems  not define
                    showForm: false
                });
            }
        });

Comment: Thank you. This works. I discover my backend (Node.js App) was not started.

But, the post request to backend is pending, checking the network capture. No error at the console

Answer (score 0):

Console.log(data) to check the response first, and maybe screen shoot and post the service for signup as any data receive will be coming from the response on  the service itself.
make sure you have a catch for the error in the signup service as well.

**Update**

in your API  you catch the error with something like :

```
return res.status(400).json({
      errorMessage: "Username already taken",
    });
  }
```

then in your front end :

```
function internalServerError(err) {
  if (err.response && err.response.data && err.response.data.errorMessage) {
    return {
      status: false,
      errorMessage: err.response.data.errorMessage,
    };
  }
  return {
    status: false,
    errorMessage: "Internal server error. Please check your server",
  };
}
```

and in your API call you can catch the error with something like this :

```
export function signup(credentials) {
  return // here your  call to the server
    .then(successStatus)
    .catch(internalServerError);
}
```

Comment: I did console data  - Console.log(data)


signup(user).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
           
        });

and have undefined

Comment: Then the issue is in your signup service you need to add a catch and return the error in that service maybe upload the code for signup

Comment: You mean signup API code at nodejs end or signup code in reactjs?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. This work. But, the post request to backend is pending, checking the network capture. No error at the console. However, the pending is pointing to this code

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {API} from '../config';

export const signup = (user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, { ----- pending status pointing to this line 
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })

    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

[image]